# encountering an error while running the simulation for SlottedFama in Unet IDE

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I'm trying to run a Slotted FAMA simulation in UNET, but I'm getting a `MissingPropertyException` when I try to create an instance of the `SlottedFama` class. When I run the code `BenchmarkedScenario1Sim.groovy` or any other sample simulation script in the Unet IDE I get this error message:

```
"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: containers for class: org.arl.fjage.DiscreteEventSimulator
Possible solutions: containers
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: containers for class: org.arl.fjage.DiscreteEventSimulator
Possible solutions: containers
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Users\syedm\Documents\unet-3.4.0\bin\S-FAMA\BenchmarkedScenario1Sim.groovy' The lookup for SlottedFama caused a failed compilation. There should not have been any compilation from this call."
```

The link to the code is https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/contrib/S-FAMA/BenchmarkedScenario1Sim.groovy

It looks like there is a problem with the line 107---> `def macAgent = new SlottedFama()`, which is causing a `MissingPropertyException`. This error message suggests that the `SlottedFama` class is not available or is not being imported correctly. Similarly if I am trying to import a class from any other script for my other code in the IDE, I am not able to do it. Maybe I am not doing it the right way.

I am using java version
openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_352-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)

and UNET version 3.4.0 and I've imported the necessary classes and dependencies. I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to fix it. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue and get my simulation running? Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Regards,
Murtaza

I tried importing the `SlottedFama.groovy` script, but the error still persists.

Comment: The code you're referring to was written for an older version of UnetStack and will need changes to run with UnetStack 3.4.0. The key difference is that the `Parameter` class (and other associated classes) have moved to fjåge (`org.arl.fjage.param`). The contributed code is user contributions, and not actively maintained by the development team.

Comment: Thank you for your response Dr. Chitre. 

I have been trying to implement Polling based MAC using the script mentioned above as reference. I am able to run my simulation in realtime but when I change the platform to DES it just freezes. 
Do I need to make any specif changes or include some additional libraries.

Comment: Seems unrelated to this question. If real-time runs ok but DES doesn’t, could possibly be a bug in fjage. You can open an issue in Unet-contrib or fjage and provide a MWE to demonstrate the problem, in order for someone to reproduce it and fix it.